# How can I update key values in realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: data structure]

I want to update key values when it removed, so I wrote codes below. These codes are in the Checkbox listener.

What I did first :

```
if(isChecked) {
    Long size = dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").getChildrenCount();
    ref_h.child(userUid).child("Bookmark").child(Long.toString(size + 1)).setValue(diningUid);
} else {
    for (int i = 1; i <= dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").getChildrenCount(); i++) {
        if (dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i)).getValue().toString().equals(diningUid)) {
            dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i)).getRef().removeValue();
            isRemoved = true;
        }
        if(isRemoved) {
            if(i != dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").getChildrenCount()){
                String newDiningUid;
                newDiningUid = dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i + 1)).getValue().toString();
                Log.d("newUID", newDiningUid);
                ref_h.child(userUid).child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i)).setValue(newDiningUid);
            } else {
                dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i)).getRef().removeValue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when the Checkbox status changes rapidly, key values are messed up.
like this

[data structure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwtlG.png)

Then I fixed the code with try-catch phrase.

```
if(isChecked) {//if not checked before listener runs, add to bookmark
    Long size = dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").getChildrenCount();
    ref_h.child(userUid).child("Bookmark").child(Long.toString(size + 1)).setValue(diningUid);
} else {//if checked before listener runs, remove from bookmark
    for (int i = 1; i <= dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").getChildrenCount(); i++) {
        try {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i)).getValue().toString().equals(diningUid)) {
                dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i)).getRef().removeValue();
                isRemoved = true;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i + 1)).getValue().toString().equals(diningUid)) {
                dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i + 1)).getRef().removeValue();
                isRemoved = true;
            }
        }
        if(isRemoved) {
            //update afterward value's index
            if(i != dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").getChildrenCount()){
                String newDiningUid;
                newDiningUid = dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i + 1)).getValue().toString();
                ref_h.child(userUid).child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i)).setValue(newDiningUid);
            } else {//remove last value
                try {
                    dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i)).getRef().removeValue();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    dataSnapshot.child("Bookmark").child(Integer.toString(i + 1)).getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't think I solved this problem.
How can I update key values properly?
or do I need to add a delay to Checkbox?
or change the data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to not use sequential numeric keys, but rely on Firebase's push IDs. For reasons on why this is a better approach and how they work, see these classic Firebase blog posts:

- [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)
- [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)

If you insist on using array-like keys, you will have to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) on the entire bookmark node to determine the next index. This is the only way to prevent the race condition that you now encounter when the array contents frequently change.

Comment: Thank you very much @Frank. Your answer was helped me a lot!